# Vue2 to Vue3 migration

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Can someone help me convert this vue wrapper to vue3 compliant code. I have tried but the components that I call my buildApp method to render are not being rendered. Is there an alternative for the Vue object imported from vue in vue3?

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import HttpServiceFactory from '@/api/HttpServiceFactory';
import { TranslationHelper } from '@/utils/mixins/Translations';
import { PermissionsHelper } from '@/utils/mixins/Permissions';
import HttpClient from '@/utils/http/HttpService';
import ApplicationConfig from '@/config/ApplicationConfig';
import ParentAccessorHelper from '@/src/helpers/plugins/ParentAccessorHelper';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import * as UtilityComponents from './utils/import';

Object.entries(UtilityComponents).forEach(([componentName, componentExport]) => {
    Vue.component(componentName, componentExport);
});

Vue.buildApp = ({ layoutId, routes = null, rootData = {} }) => {
    Vue.use(VueRouter);

    if (routes === null) {
        return new Vue({
            data() {
                return {
                    ...rootData,
                };
            },
        }).$mount(`#${layoutId}`);
    }

    const router = new VueRouter({
        mode: 'history',
        routes,
    });

    const app = new Vue({
        router,
        data() {
            return {
                isAppLoading: true,
                ...rootData,
            };
        },
    }).$mount(`#${layoutId}`);

    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
        app.isAppLoading = true;
        next();
    });

    router.afterEach(() => {
        app.isAppLoading = false;
    });

    return app;
};

export default Vue;
```

Answer (score 0):

in Vue3, There is  `createApp` function to create a vue instance.

Wish it helpes.

```
const app = createApp({});

Object.entries(UtilityComponents).forEach(([componentName, componentExport]) => {
    app.component(componentName, componentExport); 
});

app.config.globalProperties.$buildApp = () => {  
 // do something...
}

export default app;
```